# Extract a data value from page source using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

When I view a page source I am trying to extract the following data from the site using BeautifulSoup but I am unable to locate it using soup so am looking for some guidance.

When I view the source the page displays the following text.

```
var = 'SynchronizerToken';
var = 'dd3a0c31e365c458d2d3e68e3c98f772bd2103eccf381';
```

The code I am using now is

SynchronizerToken = soup.find_all("VAR SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN_VALUE")

Advice is appreciated, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expression capturing group:

```
var SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN_VALUE = '(.+?)'
```

, you can get the captured group using [`<MatchObject>.group(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group)

---

```
import re

html = '''
var SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN_NAME = 'SynchronizerToken';
var SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN_VALUE = 'dd3a0c31e365c458d2d3e68e3c98f772bd2103eccf38163e10ce039c2b70a61a';
'''

token = None
matched = re.search(r"var SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN_VALUE = '(.+?)'", html)
if matched:
    token = matched.group(1)

# token => 'dd3a0c31e365c458d2d3e68e3c98f772bd2103eccf38163e10ce039c2b70a61a'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex pattern to find the wanted value:

```
SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN_VALUE = \'(.*?)\'
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/969qhU/1)